# Lambda Expression to keep only modulo N index items? (without creating a new list)

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to pare a list down to just the modulo `N` items, i.e., keep only in `List A`, each item that remains, call it `item` with index `i` satisfying `i%N == 0`

My current solution is to create a new list (`listB`), and loop through the old list for items that meet this condition. (I feel that there is a better way than to create a new list?)

```
List<string> listA ; /* the list is not actually a string, 
but for our test case let's use this (populated with M=31 items for example)*/
List<string> listB = new List<string>();
int N = 3; 

for(int i=0;i<listA.Count;i++){
 if(i%N == 0)listB.Add(listA[i]);
}
```

Is there a better (performant?) way to write this in basically "one line" using lambda expressions? (Without needing to declare a new list)

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder - what's the problem with your current solution? "Probably not very performant" - if you show me your solution I may have a different opinion

Comment: ok i'm adding my current solution... i just thought there might be a 1 line way to solve this

Comment: @Xerillio - updated so it is not about elegance, more about attempting to not create a new list for this operation... Please explain why this is being voted upon to close?

Comment: Maybe this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netcore-3.1 ?

Comment: I added a suggested answer. Downvoting is used to make you aware that your question is lacking information or otherwise not making it's relevance clear

Comment: _Is there a better (performant?)_ - this depends on how you are using the result

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method combining the efficiency of only handling the items you're interested in while also avoiding creating a new list (though if you create the list with the known size before hand it shouldn't be that bad performance wise).

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetNthItems<T>(this List<T> source, int n)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Count; i += n)
        {
            yield return source[i];
        }
    }
}
```

And you can then enumerate them directly:

```
foreach (var myItem in listA.GetNthItems(3))
{
    //do something
}
```

But admittedly I doubt there is that much performance gain if you declare  `listB` like `listB = new List<string>((listA.Count / N)+1);` and use `i += N` inside the loop.

Edit:
As requested a way to edit the existing list in place

```
public static void ClearAllButNthItems<T>(this List<T> source, int n)
{
    var i = 1;
    for (; i * n < source.Count; i++)
    {
        source[i] = source[i * n];
    }
    source.RemoveRange(i, source.Count - i);
}
```

Which can then be used like:
`listA.ClearAllButNthItems(100);`

This first moves all nth items in order to the front of the list, then removes all remaining items (this is a constant time action* since we're removing the end of the list so no items require moving)

Edit 2:
*It seems the removal is not actually constant time since the list seems to internally create a new array during the `RemoveRange`, however the list itself stays the same.

Comment: is there a way to have the GetNthItem replace the original list without creating a new list?

Comment: @ina I added an extension method that modifies the current list in place.

Comment: is creating a new list or clearallbutnth more performant?

Comment: @ina I would advise to benchmark that for your specific scenario. My guess would be `ClearAllButNth` could be slightly ahead, however if the new list is initialized with the correct size it'll probably don't be far off (hard to guess since i don't know exactly how the internal `RemoveRange` performs. But it's all hard to say, you've never mentioned how you're going to use the result list so depending on that different options might be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
myList.Where((item, index) => index % N == 0)
```

A performant solution:

```
var resultList = new List<SomeType>();

for (var n = 0; n < myList.Count; n += N)
    resultList.Add(myList[n]);
```

Comment: great, i still don't really get lambda expressions, was trying to figure out how to write the first line. also can I just assign that back to `myList = myList.Where((item, index) => index % N == 0);`

Comment: @ina The LINQ `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, so you can't assign that to a `List` variable. What you can do is add `.ToList()` at the end - this of course is gonna create a new list

Comment: hmm so is there no way to avoid creating a new list to "pare down" an old list? 

hmm at least it avoids writing out the `for` loop

Comment: would writing a list extension operation to "pare down" be more performant?

Comment: @ina The only way to avoid creating a new list is to remove the items of the list itself. But why are you trying to avoid creating a new list? Creating objects in C# is a cheap operation. (btw if you think your question is answered, remember to accept it :))

Comment: @ina Whether it's an extension method or not doesn't change its performance. In any case, we're talking microscopic performance improvements here (don't waste time on premature optimizations)

Comment: ... currently pare-down is happening every frame, due to the list being generated from a closed-source SDK. also there are many lists each frame!